# How to parse $\sum_{i=0}^n A_i + B$?

Tags: summation, notation

If we have an expression of the form $\sum_{i=0}^n A_i + B$, does that mean $\sum_{i=0}^n (A_i + B)$, or  $(\sum_{i=0}^n A_i) + B$? Is there some accepted convention?

Comment: It is not really clear. Maybe you can give more context. But I think, if they meant the first one, they could have easily written it outside of the sum, multiplying by n.

Comment: Usually the second.

Comment: The latter. I think the best way to write it is $B+\sum_{i=0}^n A_i$ to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that there is no typo in the source where this comes from, then the sum only belongs to $A_i$ not $B$.

Actually, it's up to you in what form to write, but make sure the later reader won't encounter any difficulty to understand :)